# Track thank you page with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I will have several "thank you" pages on my site for similar form submits.

I would like to avoid using the url tracking

Would it be possible to create an event that I can add to every thank you page? Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(
['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-4'],
['_trackPageview', '/thankyou']
);
} catch (err) {}
</script>
```

Pressume the page will result in 2 page views? (as I already have a full GA code on this page which tracks the actual page view

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will result in two pageviews, one with the actual url and one with the virtual url "/thankyou".

If all your forms have the same thankyou page you can setup a goal in the Analytics backup (however a goal is counted only once per user session).

An event tracking call with ga.js would look like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form Submission', 'Name of the form', 'url of thankyou page' , 0 ,true ]);
```

where the parameters are event catogory, event label, event action, event value (to measure non-monetary goals in $$$) and non-interaction (if set to true the event will not affect your bounce rate, so it's not really necessary to set this on the thankyou page which will not have bounces in any case).

For more details [see documentation.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide)

Comment: Thanks a lot! My forms will use different thankyou pages. Maybe 3-4 different. Maybe i should just set up those as goals?

Comment: Yes, if it's okay to have four different goals, I assumed you wanted to report a single number for all submission. But different goals is certainly the easiest way.

Comment: Yes, I would prefer to report a single number. Any idea?

Comment: See my answer above - use an event (with the same event category) for alle thankyou pages. Unlike virtual pagesviews event tracking will not  inflate your pageviews, and you can set a goal based on the event category.

Comment: One question remain, how do I make it to trigger at page open? Goal still only counted once per session, right?

Comment: I solved that one. Thanks for your help. You dont know how good it was. finally the coin came down!! below is the code I used to fire it <body onload="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form Submission', 'Name of the form', 'url of thankyou page' , 0 ,true ]);">